# How to set SharePoint list add new form to set custom default form?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, custom-form, list-form

I have uploaded the custom add new form into SharePoint list. and I have tried the below PowerShell script for set as default add new form .

```
$listname = "List1"
$web = Get-SPWeb http://SiteUrl
$list = $web.lists[$listname]
$list.DefaultNewFormUrl="SiteUrl/ListName/NewForm.aspx"
```

but I got error :- 
Exception setting "DefaultNewFormUrl": "Unable to find an SPForm matching URL"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$listname = "List1"
$web = Get-SPWeb http://SiteUrl
$list = $web.lists[$listname]
$list.DefaultNewFormUrl = $list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/NewForm.aspx"
```

Comment: It's not working for me.it throws same error.but the list URL location is correct.suggest an another idea.